# Strongswan 5.7.x not sending intermediate certificate

Tags: windows, certificate, certificate-authority, strongswan

I am attempting to use a letsencrypt certificate on my strong swan server; but I also see this behaviour with my own internal CA.

When trying to connect from a windows 10 host to a strong swan instance, the Windows host displays one of it's oh-so-helpful error messages that the "IKE Authentication credentials are not acceptable".

When I install the *intermediate* certificate authority certificate onto the windows host, everything connects just fine. When I do not have the intermediate present on the client, (but it is in the cacerts folder on the strong swan server), I receive the error.

So it seems to me that strong swan is not sending the intermediate certificate, but having spent several hours chasing this around I'm at a loss as to how to force the sending of the intermediate cert. I can see that it is sending the end entity cert in the logs, but there is no mention of the intermediate.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: This lacks any information as to how StrongSwan is configured, my best guess is you're providing LE's cert.pem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that, at least for the version of strongswan I have installed on Debian Buster, that Strongswan refuses to load the intermediate certificate into it's store without the whole certificate chain being present; that is to say I had to download the root certificate and also add that under the cacerts folder, and now everything works as expected.